# Powershell New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-5.0

I try to add [New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649824(v=wps.630).aspx) with custom settings. As per Technet, there is possible options for `MultipleInstances` and including `StopExisting` value.

[image]

But actual powershell allows me choose only `Parallel`, `Queue` or `IgnoreNew`.

Why I can't use `StopExisting`?

Comment: Where is that screenshot from and what OS are you using.

Comment: @Matt That's a screenshot from the [MSDN documentation for the `TaskMultipleInstancesPolicy` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.scheduledjob.taskmultipleinstancepolicy(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look how the `MultipleInstances` property is defined, you'll see that it's type is *not* actually [`TaskMultipleInstancePolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.scheduledjob.taskmultipleinstancepolicy(v=vs.85).aspx), but a generated type named `MultipleInstancesEnum`:

```
PS C:\>(New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet |Get-Member MultipleInstances).Definition
System.Object MultipleInstances {get=[Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum]($this.PSBase.CimInstanceProperties['MultipleInstances'].Value);set=$this.PSBase.CimInstanceProperties['MultipleInstances'].Value = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum]($args[0]);}
```

This has been filed as a [bug on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/813596/stop-a-scheduled-task-if-the-task-is-already-running), upvote it if you want it changed.

The reporter also suggests a workaround to set the value to `StopExisting`:

```
$StopExisting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$StopExisting.CimInstanceProperties['MultipleInstances'].Value=3
```

Comment: Tested, works like a charm, thanks! Also upvoted MS Connect ticket.

Comment: Great info, been banging my head trying to figure out what I was missing.

Comment: [Bug on UserVoice, Connect has been discontinued](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33963487-add-stopexisting-as-a-valid-argument-for-new-sch)