# PowerShell unable to use enum MultipleInstances

Tags: powershell, enums, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am looking to use Powershell to set "if the task is already running, then the following rules applies: to  "Do not start a new instance"

[image]

my powershell script looks like below:

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyJob"
$Task.Settings.MultipleInstances= "StopExisting"
Set-ScheduledTask -User "USER" -Password "PASS" $Task
```

I get error as :

```
Exception setting "MultipleInstances": "Cannot convert value "StopExisting" to type 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum". Error: "Unable to match the 
identifier name StopExisting to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Parallel, Queue, IgnoreNew""
```

When I set $Task.Settings.MultipleInstances to Parallel, Queue and Ignorenew , it works.  Just "StopExisting" fails.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383507(v=vs.85).aspx

I looked over the StackOverflow and found similar problem: [Powershell New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241031/powershell-new-scheduledtasksettingsset)

I updated my script as :

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyJob"
$StopExisting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$StopExisting.CimInstanceProperties['MultipleInstances'].Value = 3
$Task.Settings.MultipleInstances= $StopExisting
Set-ScheduledTask -User "USER" -Password "PASS" $Task
```

Now I get different error as:

```
Exception setting "MultipleInstances": "Cannot convert the "MSFT_TaskSettings3" value of type 
"Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_TaskSettings3" to type 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum"."
At C:\temp\PythonService\WatchListPowerShell.ps1:13 char:1
+ $Task.Settings.MultipleInstances= $StopExisting
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptSetValueRuntimeException
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here and how can I solve this?

Thanks All.

Comment: Sadly I'm on Win 7, so can't test this; however, have you tried: `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum]::StopExisting`?

Comment: Alternatively, try: `[System.Enum]::GetNames('Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum')` to see if StopExisting is listed / if it's somehow spelt differently to how you expect?

Comment: Looks like it's not supported; yet...: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1805488/cmdlet-new-scheduledtasksettingsset-parameter-multipleinstances-multipleinstancesenum-doesnt-support-stopexisting-value

Comment: Thanks John. I tried your suggestions. No luck :(

Comment: You can export a scheduled task to an xml and import it with schtasks if you want to copy it to other computers.